# JBoss Classloading ClassCastException JCA Issue

Tags: jboss6.x, jca

I have a problem accessing a jndi connection via my JCA adaptor. I'm getting a ClassCastException when I try to access the connection. Several visits to StackOverflow told me I have to limit my copies of the jar class in question to one, however I cannot do that since my JCA adaptor needs the jar and off course its also needed in my ear.

So I needed to use the shared library for jboss. How do I force my ear and JCA to use the server/default/lib to load the classes. I have copied the jars to my server installation jboss-eap-6.4.0\standalone\lib. Doing so makes my ear fail with NoClassDefinition found.

Maybe the default lib won't work? if not can someone maybe tell me what I can use alternatively maybe someone at JBOSS should supply a configurable feature to switch off hierarchical class loading since its more trouble than its worth :(.

Please help!

Stacktrace (IIDKitConnection is an interface on IDKitConnection)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: za.cs.face.abis.jca.IDKitConnection cannot be cast to za.cs.face.abis.jca.IIDKitConnection
at za.co.face.common.util.GenAbisServiceLocator.getIDKit(GenAbisServiceLocator.java:53) [abis-common-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at za.co.face.test.HelloWorldSessionBean.sayHello(HelloWorldSessionBean.java:26) [HelloWorld.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:258) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:347) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at za.co.face.test.HelloWorldSessionLocal$$$view2.sayHello(Unknown Source) [HelloWorld.jar:]
at za.co.face.test.HelloWorldWebService.sayHello(HelloWorldWebService.java:28) [HelloWorld.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:280) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:129)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:177)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_77]
```

GenAbisServiceLocator.getIDKit

```
 idKit = (IDKit) ((za.cs.face.abis.jca.IIDKitConnection) ic.lookup("java:/jca/IDKit")).getConnection();
```

Extraction standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="JCA_IDKit_RAR_2.53-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.rar">
                <archive>
                    JCA_IDKit_RAR_2.53-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="za.cs.face.abis.jca.IDKitManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/jca/IDKit" enabled="true" pool-name="IDKitManagedConnectionFactory_Pool">
                        <security>
                            <application/>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        </validation>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
```

IDKitConnection class in my JCA adaptor

```
public class IDKitConnection implements IIDKitConnection, Serializable, Referenceable
```

In the adaptor I have the interface inside the abis_common.jar and also in the modules for jboss

Comment: Welcome to stck overflow :-) I think it would be helpful if you give more information, i.e. the stacktrace, your project setup ...

Comment: I have updated my post. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It is apparently a bug in JBOSS.

I've removed all dependency references in my EJB and just added the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and it WORKED!!!!

I'm posting the useful link here although I didn't get the same error it is the same issue.

[JCA and Class Loading in WildFly](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/260872?start=0&tstart=0)

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">  
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>  
<sub-deployment name="HelloWorld.jar">  
    <dependencies>  
        <module name="deployment.JCA_IDKit_RAR_2.53-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.rar" />  
    </dependencies>  
</sub-deployment></jboss-deployment-structure>
```